# Cannot save product attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I've created an attribute in Magento 2 of the Input Type Dropdown. I am facing this issue when trying to add a new option value to that attribute and saving. Error is "The value of Admin must be unique".
[image]

Comment: You can not set duplicate value in select attribute in admin section.. post your code or screenshot where you get error.

Comment: @Rizwan There are no any duplicates values display in attribute option section. I've attached screenshot of the error. This error is coming when I was trying to add last red color highlighted option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check you use `Peppermint` in your attribute value twise or not.

Magento2 can not allow you to add duplicate Values of Your Attribute. Please add unique value for attribute value.

Check this, it will work for you.

Comment: Now its working or not?

Comment: Other tabs values also couldn't edit. I've tried to edit Manage Labels, but it was also not working.I'm getting the same error message every time. "The value of Admin must be unique."

Comment: Remove Values of Your Attribute and re-enter it and check.

Comment: This error is onlu occurred when you add any duplicate value. So check it first or else re-enter it.

Comment: Previous data import was done by magento 1 to magento 2 data migration tool. There was few duplicates attribute option values. After removed all duplicate values successfully save newly added attribute value. Thanks.